# module 'app.forms' has no attribute 'JobsFormSet'

Tags: python, django

I've have something like this in django: "module 'app.forms' has no attribute 'JobsFormSet'"

views.py:

http://pastebin.com/Kwup5s1x

forms.py:

http://pastebin.com/WyMuW3vn

I don't know where is a problem. I'm beginner in django. I'm pretty sure this code is correct, because I'm using from this tutorial (in polish)

Comment: I don't think you have formatted your forms.py example, as the indentation isn't correct.  It may be related to your problem, but can't say until the formatting is correct.

Comment: formatting is correct

Comment: No it isn't. The views.py wouldn't even compile; you would get an InconsistentIndentationError.

Comment: Your Meta for CustomerForm is outside the class definition as well. Showing your template would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Th error you get is

> module 'app.forms' has no attribute 'JobsFormSet'

which probably comes from the lines

```
form = self.get_form()
jobs = forms.JobsFormSet(self.request.POST)
```

since you try to get JobsFormSet attribute in "forms" instead of "form".

Try this:

```
jobs = form.JobsFormSet(self.request.POST)
```

Comment: Exception Value:  

module 'app.forms' has no attribute 'JobsFormSet'

Exception Location:  C:\Users\stoton\PycharmProjects\tut\app\views.py in get_context_data, line 27 still, it is this  context['jobs'] = forms.JobsFormSet()